# Reset the data on table using reset button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, for-loop

learning javascript by doing (beginner), here i have a table where is 'animals' and 'persons' want to know is there a way to reset table data back to 'Animal' after selecting data from select box ? i thought by calling the whole thing again inside onclick would do the trick but...

my code :

```js
function myFunction() {
paivitys()
}

function paivitys(data, arvvoja) {
  console.log(data);
  //----
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("animal")) {
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = data.animal;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = data.person;
    document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = 'person';
  }
  //----  
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("animal2")) {
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = data.animal2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = data.person2;
    document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = 'person';
  }

  //----- 
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data.id;
}

function paivitaselekt(data, arvvoja) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    arvvoja.forEach((value) => {
      option.textContent += data[i][value] + " ";
    });
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}

data = {
  "animal": "tiger",
  "animal2": "lion",
  "id": "54321",
  "dole": {
    "Key": "fhd699f"
  }
}

paivitys(data);
let kokoarray;

data = [{
    "person": "kaka",
    "person2": "julle",
    "id": "9874",
  },
  {
    "person": "Ronaldo",
    "person2": "jussi",
    "id": "65555",
  }
]
kokoarray = data;
paivitaselekt(data, ["person", "id"]);

document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  const valittutunnsite = event.target.value.split(" ")[1];
  const valittutieto = kokoarray.filter((data) => data.id === valittutunnsite)[0];
  paivitys(valittutieto);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <table class="table ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25%;" id="1name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;" id="2name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;" class="table-primary">id</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <th id="1name"></th>
      <th id="2name"></th>
      <th id="id"></th>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <select id="Select" name="name"></select>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain precisely what you have at the beginning and what you want to have at the end.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 as you can see in beginning there are 'animals', when user selects from select box it changes to 'person' i want to click reset button and bring back 'animals'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works this.

```js
   
let animals
let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2']
let peopleCols = ['Person', 'Person 2']

function myFunction() {
  paivitys(animals, animalCols)
}

function paivitys(data, arvvoja) {
  console.log(data);
  //----
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("animal")) {
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = data.animal;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = data.person;
  }
  //----  
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("animal2")) {
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = data.animal2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = data.person2;
    
  }

  document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[0];
  document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[1];

  //----- 
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data.id;
}

function paivitaselekt(data, arvvoja) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    arvvoja.forEach((value) => {
      option.textContent += data[i][value] + " ";
    });
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}

animals = {
  "animal": "tiger",
  "animal2": "lion",
  "id": "54321",
  "dole": {
    "Key": "fhd699f"
  }
}

paivitys(animals, animalCols);
let kokoarray;

people = [{
    "person": "kaka",
    "person2": "julle",
    "id": "9874",
  },
  {
    "person": "Ronaldo",
    "person2": "jussi",
    "id": "65555",
  }
]
kokoarray = people;
paivitaselekt(kokoarray, ["person", "id"]);

document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  const valittutunnsite = event.target.value.split(" ")[1];
  const valittutieto = kokoarray.filter((data) => data.id === valittutunnsite)[0];
  paivitys(valittutieto, peopleCols);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <table class="table ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25%;" id="1name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;" id="2name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;" class="table-primary">id</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <th id="1name"></th>
      <th id="2name"></th>
      <th id="id"></th>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <select id="Select" name="name"></select>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

I updated the code:

set columns

```
let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2']
let peopleCols = ['Person', 'Person 2']
```

udpate data

```
paivitys(animals, animalCols)
```

and

```
function paivitys(data, arvvoja) {
  ...
  document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[0];
  document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[1];
  //...
}
```

Comment: could you bring also 'animal', like reset whole thing

Comment: This doesn't explain to the author what he has done wrong.

Comment: @walee i don't understand

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z with resetting it should go to beginning, like bring these also back :  <th style="width: 25%;" id="1name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;" id="2name1" class="table-primary">Animal</th>

Comment: @Franklin'j Gil'z this very good answer and i will accept it, but i have one question, now data is so small its good to do it this way, what if data was ten times greater than this, then, should we write all that data here : let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2']
, wouldnt it be time consuming ? could you possibly also write example of that if you want cuz it was not the real question : )

Comment: If you add a new colum in your table, you must add it in animalCols and peopleCols. 
Otherwise you will see it empty. you can create a dynamic table, example: https://jsfiddle.net/Luo4vbhm/

Comment: you can add multiple cols

Answer (score 0):

Your reset button calls the function:

`function myFunction() {
paivitys()
}`

Which calls the `paivitys` function with no arguments.

`function paivitys(data, arvvoja) {`

The function takes `data` as its first argument, but you are not passing any variable to it.

This line is failing:

`if (data.hasOwnProperty("animal")) {`

Because `data` is undefined.

But as well as this, you are defining your data using animals, and then later changing the data to contain people. So the animals data is lost. You need to use a different variable to store people data.

Comment: if you can make this code easier (simpler) for beginner feel free to share it here :)

Comment: There wasn't really anything wrong with the method you are using, I just told you why it wasn't working. You could have worked it out yourself from this, it was a minor mistake.